# What is the PayPal API base link for Live accounts?

Tags: javascript, paypal, e-commerce

I am implementing standard integration, but I cannot send money to my live client ID,

The pop up disappears with an error after I click it

I noticed the paypal-api.js script points to

```
const { CLIENT_ID, APP_SECRET } = process.env;
const base = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com";
```

Maybe this base link needs to be changed to live.

What is the correct link? Or is there any other issue that might cause this problem?

I tried changing to https://api-m.live.paypal.com and https://api-m.paypal.com butthe same issue persists, as soon as I click on any of the paypal buttons, the popup immediately disappears. I dont have a pop up blocker enabled, and this works with Sandbox Client-ID and Secrt

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The live URLs are the same as sandbox just without `sandbox.`.  So,  https://api-m.paypal.com

The problem of the popup opening and immediately disappearing occurs when the frontend JS cannot obtain a valid order ID from the backend, for whatever reason.  Begin by reproducing with the Network tab open and cleared, and look at the communication between your frontend JS and the create order route it is fetching. Any number of things could be wrong, if the error is coming from your server then that is where you need to solve the problem, which could be invalid live API credentials, invalid environment/URLs, or any number of other problems.